# Selenium - TestNG Sequence in individual test vs testsuite

Tags: java, selenium, maven, annotations, testng

I developed a POM test framework in maven in eclipse IDE. Currently I have 3 test files. Each test file has

1)constructor - which calls the Base class methods to setup and launches browser.
2) @Test - actual tests
3) @AfterClass - to do post test cleanup. quit driver, close file connections.

When I run them separately, they run fine. However when I run them through testng.xml as suite, it gives me trouble. It
1)launches all the browsers one after the other
2) then run the test where in control from one test goes to the other test.
3) quit only one browser.

I want my sequence of execution in testsuite to be like following.

1. Launch browser for test file 1
2. run test
   3)quit browser
   4)Launch  browser for test file 2
3. run test
   6)quit browser and so on.

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please suggest. Following is the code in my base class.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package seleniumeasy.qa.Base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import seleniumeasy.qa.Util.commonUtil;

/**
 * @author sanee
 *
 */
public class Base {
    
    protected static WebDriver driver=null;
    private static FileInputStream fis;
    private static Properties prop;
    
    public Base()
    {
        System.out.println("I am in Base constructor");
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(commonUtil.sConfigPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void Init()
    {
        System.out.println("I am inside Init.");
        
        //if(driver==null)
        //{
            System.out.println("I am inside If:");
            if(prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
            {
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("chromekey"),prop.getProperty("chromepath"));
                driver = new ChromeDriver();            
            }
            if(prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("edge"))
            {
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("edgekey"),prop.getProperty("edgepath"));
                driver = new EdgeDriver();          
            }
            if(prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("ff"))
            {
                System.setProperty(prop.getProperty("ffkey"),prop.getProperty("ffpath"));
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();           
            }
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(commonUtil.iImplicitWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();        
            driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
            
            
            /*Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alt.dismiss();*/
            
            
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("No, thanks!")).click();
            
        }       
        
        
    //}
    
    public void postCleanUp(String sTestName)
    {
        System.out.println("I am in postcleanup from: + " + sTestName);
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        driver=null;
        /*try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        
    }
}
```

following is the code in one of my test classes

```
package seleniumeasy.test.Tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import seleniumeasy.qa.Base.Base;
import seleniumeasy.qa.Page.HomePage;
import seleniumeasy.qa.Page.tblPaginationPage;

public class HomePageTest extends Base 
{

    public HomePage obj;
    public tblPaginationPage tblObj;
    SoftAssert sAssert;
    
    
    
    public HomePageTest()
    {
        Init();
        obj = new HomePage();
        sAssert = new SoftAssert();
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void verifyTablePaginationMenu()
    {
        Reporter.log("Test Name is: verifyTablePaginationMenu");
        tblObj = obj.clickTablePagination();
        WebElement sPageTitle = driver.findElement(By.tagName("h2"));
        
        sAssert.assertEquals("Table with Pagination Example", sPageTitle.getText());
        
    }
    @AfterMethod    
    public void sAssertAll()
    {
        System.out.println("I am in HomePage AfterClass");
        //System.out.println("I came here");
        postCleanUp("HomePageTest");
        sAssert.assertAll();
        
    }
    /*@AfterClass
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        //postCleanUp();
    }*/
}
```

following is the code in testng.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  
<suite name="AutomationSuit" verbose="1" >
  
  
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="seleniumeasy.qa.Util.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>
  <test name="Regression">
    <classes>
      <class name="seleniumeasy.test.Tests.HomePageTest"/>
      <class name="seleniumeasy.test.Tests.TablePaginationTest"/>
      <class name="seleniumeasy.test.Tests.tblDataSearchTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

please find attached picture of my POM framework folder hierarchy for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by adding the Init() in BeforeMethod Annotation and postcleanup() in the AfterMethod Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For every class you call Init(), that is why you have three new istances of the browser.
When you are calling :

```
public void postCleanUp(String sTestName)
```

try with passing webdriver

```
public void postCleanUp(String sTestName, WebDriver driver1)
```

and do driver1.quit()

Comment: Hi, No it did not work. The output is the same as before. One browser closes but the other two remain and then it doesn't know which browser to work with.

Comment: I resolved my problem by adding the Init() in BeforeMethod Annotation and postcleanup() in the AfterMethod Annotation.